# Magento 2 Task "Update attributes for 2 selected products": 1 item(s) are currently being updated.1 item(s) have been scheduled for update

Tags: product, magento2.3, cron, queue, bulk-products-update

Magento version 2.3.5
Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image]
Cron is working fine I cross-check with indexing and when run this command -

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update
```

then the problem is solved but it's not a good way, again and again, to run these commands

Answer (score 0):

Please check indexer status in admin System -> Tools -> index. Message might be shown due to any recent bulk update.

Running cron command and re indexing command fixed this issue for me

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```